# How do I combine unicode characters?

Tags: java, unicode

I am trying to print unicode characters in java console. The problem is I am trying to use Bengali character set and I need to combine 2 unicode characters together. I have no clue how to do so. For example:  I can print  ড and া separately. When combined this should turn into: ডা . that means the circular part should not be there anymore. But I really have no idea how to do so. I tried googling but couldn't find anything relevant :/

Comment: You need a layouting engine that understands complex scripts and a font that contains the relevant glyphs and GPOS entries.

Comment: So it isn't that straight forward ,right? Could you point me to a direction where I could find a solution? Any links or so?

Comment: Maybe try ICU? It has Java bindings. It's not *trivial*, but it should be straight-forward.

Comment: Ok, I will have a look into it.

Comment: More specifically, the console would need to support complex text layout. Most don't, as combining characters and bidi tend to combine poorly with with traditional terminal features. But if you're just a normal command line application it's not really your job to do text layout. What 'Java console' are you using?

Comment: I am using eclipse's console. I didn't know much about complex layouts before actually, have been searching since yesterday only and what appears isn't very simple. I thought it would be trivial. My main target is putting it on android though. And I think android uses some kind of layout engine with complex scripts support in it's webview. So I think I will use that somehow to get my job done.

Comment: Yeah, web browsers support complex text layout much more commonly than consoles. Note Android has historically not shipped with proper support for Indic languages, so make sure to test it with different versions/phones. If you need to support versions before 4.0 you might need to muck about with custom fonts.

Comment: I tested on my phone, it is on jelly bean and complex scripts work fine on it. I think I will target the android 4.0+ phones only.

Answer (score 0):

Just use double quotes in between. It works for me in IntelliJ and Eclipse without installing any other addons.
E.g.

```
System.out.println(myUnicodeChar1+""+myUnicodeChar2+""+myUnicodeChar3);
```